# Password reset is not working

Tags: unix, password, kerberos

I am using krb5 authentication to authenticate users in my machine. I am trying to change my password using `passwd` command but it failed.

```
~:$ passwd
~:$ Changing Password for bharathi
~:$ Kerberos 5 Password: 
~:$ New Password: 
~:$ Retype new password: 
~:$ authentication error
```

**Syslog Output**

```
pam_krb5  password changed failed for bharathi: Authentication error : Authentication error
pam_unix(chauthok): authentication failure: loginname=root uid=3310 euid=0 tty=pts/36 ruser= rhost= user=bharathi
pam_unix(chauthok): user password changed by another process
```

I cannot reset my password. Please help.

Comment: which distro are you using?

Comment: Centos 6.4 final.

Comment: look at the configuration of pam modules in /etc/pam.d/*

Answer (score 0):

you need kpasswd to change a kerberos password.

This could help you:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/kpasswd.1.html